# How do I create a json object in ROR without it creating a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

For instance, if I tried to create something like this

```
@json = Array.new

for x in 0..1
    y = 2
    @json << ["Id" => x, "Label" => y]
 end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @nodes }
end
```

This is the JSON that is returned:

```
[[{"Id":0,"Label":2}], [{"Id":1,"Label":2}]]
```

Then if I want to access it in java script, I have to do `array[i][0].id` to find the id. When I should just be able to do `array[i].id` to grab the id.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you want to write `.id` why use upcase `Id` to build the hash?

Answer (score 2):

You used `[]` to build a hash, you must use `{}`. And don't initialize + loop + push, that's not idiomatic Ruby. I'd write:

```
@json = (0..1).map { |id| {"Id" => id, "Label" => 2} }
#=> [{"Id"=>0, "Label"=>2}, {"Id"=>1, "Label"=>2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing `@json << {"Id" => x, "Label" => y}` ?

Comment: I find Ruby a bit confusing in this particular case. Imho `["Id" => x, "Label" => y]` should throw exception instead of converting it into a list which contains hash.

Comment: @freakish: it's a feature so you can write array of hashes in a compact way. To be honest I don't like it either.